# What's the max # of concurrent connections / HTTP requests per sec I should make to a given domain?

Tags: http, web, connection, web-crawler, httprequest

I'm downloading a full catalog worth of **static image content** (million+ images, all legal) from various webservers.

I want to download the images efficiently, but I'm considering **what limits** per domain I should place on the **# of concurrent connections** and **time between connection attempts** to avoid being blacklisted by DOS tools and other limiters.

Comment: ask the people providing the content perhaps? It's the only way to know for *sure*.

Comment: There are potentially 1000's of webservers, not practical in the same way it's not practical for Google to call me up and ask the same question of my web server. But checking robots.txt is a reasonable idea that your comment spawns.

Comment: ah, to me "various" != "1000's" :). Then if you have many servers perhaps the way to go is a "round robin" - download N images from one server then move to the next one, cycling loads across all the servers.

Comment: Yeh, I was vague there. :)  We have gobs of compute/network capacity on our side, we want 1000's of connections running simultaneously to get done quick (we're running in a Hadoop cluster on AWS), but I don't want to slam the individual webservers and get blacklisted for a DOS attack. I need to throttle back per domain. I'm trying to decide the parameters of our throttling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword I needed to look for was "webcrawler politness", that popped up some useful articles that answer the question quite well:

[Typical politeness factor for a web crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236046/typical-politeness-factor-for-a-web-crawler)

http://blog.mischel.com/2011/12/20/writing-a-web-crawler-politeness/